# Getting response, body and error from an asynchronous method making a POST API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, asynchronous, http-post

I am using this example to make a POST API call to an API: https://nodejs.dev/making-http-requests-with-nodejs#perform-a-post-request. No issues there, it works well.

Next, I wanted to create a function that makes this API call by taking in dynamic connection parameters, headers and payload. Did that and I am able to return the response object from the function so I can detect the response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, etc. Here's my Node.js code:

**Module Code**

```
const https = require("https");

function postLendingApplication(connection, data, callback) {
  const options = {
    hostname: connection.hostname,
    port: connection.port,
    path: connection.path,
    method: connection.method,
    headers: connection.headers
  };
  //console.log(options)
  const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

    res.on("data", d => {
      process.stdout.write(d);
    });
    callback(res);
  });

  req.on("error", error => {
    console.error(error);
  });

  req.write(data);
  req.end();
}

exports.postLendingApplication = postLendingApplication;
```

**Invoking the code from another file**

```
const bpc = require("./public-api");

const data = JSON.stringify({
  title: 'foo',
  body: 'bar',
  userId: 1
});

const connection = {
    hostname: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/posts',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length,
    }
}

var response = bpc.postLendingApplication(connection, data, function(response) {
    console.log("Inside the calling function");
    //console.log(response);
    console.log("Status Code: " + response.statusCode);
    console.log("Status Message: " + response.statusMessage);
});
```

**Successful console response**

```
statusCode: 201
Inside the calling function
Status Code: 201
Status Message: Created
{
  "title": "foo",
  "body": "bar",
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 101
}
```

***Question:*** In my callback method, I would like to receive the response body (The JSON) as well as the error so I can run some assertions based on the response/body/error that I received. I am not able to figure out how to setup callback in the module method so it can return all 3 values. If you can please help out with that, it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the Repl URL in case you'd like to take a stab at it online: https://repl.it/@varun_verma/POST-API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% on the question you are asking, I personally if you are wanting to use callbacks in this way use two functions one to handle the error and one for the succsessful response

however, you can use object destruction to give you undefined or default it to null if you like for the item not passed back as shown below:

**Module Code**

```
const https = require("https");

function postLendingApplication(connection, data, callback) {
  const options = {
    hostname: connection.hostname,
    port: connection.port,
    path: connection.path,
    method: connection.method,
    headers: connection.headers
  };
  //console.log(options)
  const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
    let data = ''

    res.on("data", d => {
        data += d;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        callback({response: res, data});
    });

  });

  req.on("error", error => {
    console.error(error);
    callback({response: res, error});
  });

  req.write(data);
  req.end();
}

exports.postLendingApplication = postLendingApplication;
```

**Invoking the code from another file**

```
const bpc = require("./public-api");

const data = JSON.stringify({
  title: 'foo',
  body: 'bar',
  userId: 1
});

const connection = {
    hostname: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/posts',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': data.length,
    }
}

var response = bpc.postLendingApplication(connection, data, function({ response, data, error}) {
    // if error is not passed back in the object it defaults to undefined
    if (error) console.error(error)
    console.log("Inside the calling function");
    //console.log(response);
    console.log("Status Code: " + response.statusCode);
    console.log("Status Message: " + response.statusMessage);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have the response, data, and the error passed to the callback. (where you currently only pass the response)

You can pass the data to the callback like so:

```
const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
    let data = '';

    res.on("data", d => {
        data += d;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        callback(res, data);
    });
});
```

This buffers the data from the response as it comes in into a string and then only when the response ends passes both the response object and the data as a string to the callback. (you can then use JSON.parse in the callback to convert the data string to an object)

Passing the error is more difficult as the error callback is given separately from the response. I would recommend having a separate callback for the error:

```
function postLendingApplication(connection, data, callback, error_callback) {
...
    req.on("error", error => {
        console.error(error);
        error_callback(error);
    });
...
}
```

However someone else on here may be able to give a better solution for the error.